# What kind of checkmate pattern is this?

Tags: tactics, checkmate, patterns

I played this game and was wondering, is this a checkmate pattern with a name?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not have a name. For a list of the names of most common patterns, Wikipedia has a good article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkmate_pattern#Epaulette_mate).